# Non-conformable arrays in the context of optimization

Tags: r, optimization

I'll show my problem in a way that can be reproduced.

```r
somefunc <- function(values, weightvec) crossprod(values, weightvec)
tiny <- data.matrix(c(2293244, 2301521, 2318491, 2334855, 2350360, 2357444))
vec <- data.matrix(rep(1/3, 3))
roll <- data.matrix(unlist(lapply(seq(nrow(tiny) - 3 + 1), function(i) somefunc(tiny[i - 1 + seq(3), ], vec))))
```

The `roll` is `somefunc` applied to rows 1 through 3, then 2 through 4, etc. I will try to manipulate `tiny` in such a way to match the `zeros_ones` as shown below

```r
zeros_ones <- data.matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

Since `roll` reduces the number of rows of `tiny` I have a function which does the same to the matrix `zeros_ones`

```r
deltat <- 3
truth <- data.matrix(zeros_ones[-1:-(deltat - 1), ])
```

Putting it all together, and returning a score, is this function:

```r
fxn <- function(deltat, thres) { 
    truth <- data.matrix(zeros_ones[-1:-(deltat - 1), ])
    income <- data.matrix(unlist(lapply(seq(nrow(tiny) - deltat + 1), function(i) somefunc(tiny[i - 1 + seq(deltat), ], data.matrix(rep(1/deltat, deltat))))))
    income[income < thres] <- 1
    income[income != 1] <- 0
    FP <- length(which(income == 1 & truth == 0))
    FN <- length(which(income == 0 & truth == 1))
    TP <- length(which(income == 1 & truth == 1))
    TN <- length(which(income == 0 & truth == 0))
    return(2 * (TP/(TP + FP)) * (TP/(TP + FN))/((TP/(TP + FP)) + (TP/(TP + FN))))
}
```

This will produce a value of 0.67 when I enter `test <- fxn(3, 2350000)`.

Now when I copy the function and introduce some bounds in an attempt to optimize, I get an error.

```r
fn <- function(input) {
    deltat <- input[1]
    thres <- input[2]
    truth <- data.matrix(zeros_ones[-1:-(deltat - 1), ])
    income <- data.matrix(unlist(lapply(seq(nrow(tiny) - deltat + 1), function(i) somefunc(tiny[i - 1 + seq(deltat), ], data.matrix(rep(1/deltat, deltat))))))
    income[income < thres] <- 1
    income[income != 1] <- 0
    FP <- length(which(income == 1 & truth == 0))
    FN <- length(which(income == 0 & truth == 1))
    TP <- length(which(income == 1 & truth == 1))
    TN <- length(which(income == 0 & truth == 0))
    return(1 - ((2 * (TP/(TP + FP)) * (TP/(TP + FN)))/((TP/(TP + FP)) + (TP/(TP + FN)))))
}

x0 <- c(3, 2350000)
lb <- c(2, 2200000)
ub <- c(3, 2500000)

library(nloptr)    
isres(fn = fn, x0 = x0, lower = lb, upper = ub, maxeval = 100000)
```

```
Error in income == 1 & truth == 0 : non-conformable arrays
```

I don't know how a function can work without issue outside of optimization, but return this error when I try to optimize. I believe R thinks the arrays `income` and `truth` have a non-equal number of rows, but again, this is not the case when I run `fxn` on its own.

Comment: The dimensions of `income` and `truth` are a function of `deltat`. There exists `deltat` between 2 and 3 for which their dimensions differ. Why are you optimizing `deltat` at all, given that only the integer values 2 and 3 are valid?

Comment: In the real problem, many integers are valid. Zeros_ones is a binary vector showing recession or not. I have a number of economic time series' and I want to see 1. which manipulation of the series is best and 2. what is the threshold below which recession is likely. Is it 1 mo change in 3 mo expon smth moving average? Or 2 mo change in 5 mo EMA? For example

Comment: OK - but `isres` does not know that `deltat` needs to be an integer.  It is choosing floating point values between 2 and 3, for which the dimensions of `income` and `truth` can be non-conformable.

Answer (score 0):

`round(deltat)` in the optimization function fixed it. In my real problem I had another value whereby using `round()` was necessary.